Understanding representation of Vector in matrix form, the way vector transform when multiplied by matrix.
I have a basic understanding of what is linear trasformation but I am struggling with convention and representation in mathematical format.
I am trying to understand the representation. How to represent this in matrix, shouldn't it be $A_{ij}$ instead of as given above??
$$ \phi(e_i)= \sum_i A_{ji}e_j  $$
where $\phi$ is a linear function associating every vector $x$ to $\phi(x)$ and $e_i$ are basis vectors . I am thinking it should be of the form for $\mathbb{R}^3$ as given below, I know it's not correct but I am not able to imagine aything other than this .
$$\begin{bmatrix}\phi(e_1)\\\phi(e_2)\\\phi(e_3)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}e_1\\e_2\\e_3\end{bmatrix}$$
I would be very obliged if someone points out what's wrong with my understanding or the way of approach.

$e_i$ and $\phi(e_i)$ are vectors, not scalars, so your representation is flawed

The representation is $\phi = A$, i.e. $\phi(e_i) = Ae_i = A_{\cdot, i} = \sum_{j = 1}^{3}a_{j, i}e_j$. The fix to your picture is
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    \phi (e_1) & \phi (e_2) & \phi (e_3)
  \end{array}\right) & = & \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    a_{1 1} & a_{1 2} & a_{1 3}\\
    a_{2 1} & a_{2 2} & a_{2 3}\\
    a_{3 1} & a_{3 2} & a_{3 3}
  \end{array}\right)  \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    e_1 & e_2 & e_3
  \end{array}\right) .
\end{eqnarray*}
